# Multiple id selector with same parent class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please suggest me a simplification code for below code snippet,

```
$('.classA #Id1, .classA #Id2').on('change', e => {
    // Do Action
});
```

Can you please suggest simplification of `$('.classA #Id1, .classA #Id2')` line? Thanks

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique across the DOM (that's the point of IDs). You don't need a parent class or anything else, just select them directly. `$('#Id1, #Id2')`

Comment: $('parentSelector').find('child1, child2');

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve... if you want to run the code on all `classA` elements then simply use `$('.classA')`. If you want to run only on elements `#Id1` and `#Id2`, then as Jeremy mentioned above user `$('#Id1, #Id2')`